# how do you "transfer" classes in java?

Tags: java

i'm trying to "import" (i don't think thats the right term though.) a class, from a class, with/via IF statements. what syntax should i use?

i tried using import package.testclass, but i dunno what to do from there.

```
//this is the first class,

import java.util.Scanner;
import package.testclass;

public class Main
{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the word TEST to test if your code block worked.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String test = sc.nextLine();

    if (test.equals("TEST")){
        System.out.print("tranferring class...");

    }


}
}

   //while this is the second class.

   public class testclass
               {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("you managed to transfer classes! 
    hurrei!:D");
    }
    }
```

so the IF is incomplete, and i kinda wanted for the system to print out the thing in the 2nd class. so basically, when i enter "TEST" in main, it should print "you managed to transfer classes! hurrei! :D", which is on another class

Comment: All public classes should be in there own *.java  file.  Also usually the `main` class is the entry point for any program and so usually there is only one.

Comment: yea, that was separate files, and i just posted both here.

Comment: `testclass.main(args);` (immediately after `System.out.print("tranferring class...");`) - and that is executing a method (nothing about "importing").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have worked, did you get any issues?

```
if (test.equals("TEST")){
    System.out.print("tranferring class...");
    testclass.main(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you could have a meaningful method in your class.

```
public class Testclass
{
    public void printMessage(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

this then can be instantiated and called

```
Testclass tc = new Testclass ();
tc.printMessage ("say something");
```

Note that class names usually start with an Upper case letter and methods don't